# Hi everyone, I`m sitting with a simple swap issue in C++ (two strings). I cant get my swap to work.My output is only "splendid day"

Tags: arrays, string, indexing, char, swap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string a, b, temporary; // function to swap s and d (splendid day to dplendid say)

    cout << "Input two words: " << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cin.get(); //capture user input // to add index parameters?

    temporary = a[0]; //assign temp variable to a[0]
    b[0] = a[0];  //allocate b to a
    b[0] = temporary;  //do swap
    swap(a[0], b[0]);

    cout << "The two words you entered are: " << a << " " << b << endl; //attempt output


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are only swapping the first character of the strings.  `a[0]` is the first character of `a`, and likewise for `b`.

Second, you are swapping twice:  Once with `std::swap` and once using three assignments and a temporary.  Swapping twice puts it back the way it started!

## swap once

```
temporary = a[0]; //assign temp variable to a[0]
b[0] = a[0];  //allocate b to a
b[0] = temporary;  //do swap
```

## swap again

```
swap(a[0], b[0]);
```

Comment: Interesting - if I take swap(a[0], b[0]) out of the program, just declaring the variables and temp as char type, nothing happens. But when I add swap(a[0], b[0]) plus swap(b[0], a[0]) it works - I never would have guessed.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.  Calling `swap` twice (changing the order of the parameters doesn't matter) should put it back the way it started.

Comment: P.S. you might look into the [*Code Review* Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap the first character of each string just do the swap (not both the swap and the manual operation via the temporary):

```
swap(a[0], b[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with the code -

1. You need to declare temporary as char

```
 string a, b; // function to swap s and d (splendid day to dplendid say)
    char temporary;
```

2. Assign temporary the value at b[0]

```
temporary = b[0]; //assign temp variable to b[0]
```

3. Assign a[0] the value temporary

```
a[0]= temporary;
```

This much is enough for swapping once. The swap function at the end will undo these changes so either remove that or do not swap the chars manually.

This solved it on my end and I got dplendid say as output.